# C++ Error C2440 when using exisiting C source

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I am having an issue where I have a C2440 error when compiling a C++ project in VS2005. The error is due some existing C code in another project which I depend on which casts a void pointer to either a char or int pointer.

The code resembles:

```
void * bbb;
... // some code which defines the void pointer
int * aaa = bbb;
```

However in C++ I need to specifically cast the type to be valid such as:

```
int * aaa = (int *)bbb;
```

My question is whether there exists a flag or compile option in VS2005 which allows my to compile my main project in C++ and ignore this error from depending projects I want to compile as C?

I would rather not change any of the original source as it is a shared project.

Comment: compile the C source code as C

Comment: I already have the /TC flag for the project I depend on. So I assume it is building as C. It build on its own fine.

Comment: I can use the -fpermissive flag in gcc to ignore the non-conforming code and make the compiler ignore this error - is their no similar function in VS?

Comment: OT(?): You are casting to the wrong type: `int * aaa = (int)bbb;` should be `int * aaa = (int *)bbb;`

Comment: typo - updated in edit. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this was to edit the header files which caused the problem. It turned out to be a minor number of files which could be merged back into the shared projects.

There is no way to get around this in VisualC++. I had used `-fpermissive` to ignore the error in gcc.

So I just made the update to:

```
int * aaa = (int *)bbb;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you name the file "something.c", the compiler will [unless explicitly told otherwise] compile it as `C` (and thus happily accept your pointer conversion without using a cast). A file named "something.cpp" will be compiled as C++, and you will need a cast to convert a pointer to a different type, even if it's a `void` pointer.

Comment: Something I left out of the question, the function is declared as an inline in a header file so the compiler can't use the extension to direct the compiler.

Comment: Well, then you will have to fix the code, I'm afraid. Either add the cast, or make the function "not inline".

Comment: Thanks Mats. Yes I have chosen to fix the shared projects. Cheers.